# TCustomControl executing Keyboard events

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl

I have a TCustomControl descendant working well, but a TCustomControl is missing code (Like a hit message or something) to drive keyboard events KeyDown, KeyUp etc.
I understand TCustomControl is a descendant of TWinControl and so is TForm, but I do not know what to look for in TForm that drive its keyboard events. I Just cannot see it. I no wish to take up the TForm's keyboard events externally so they cannot be used in standard Delphi Code. Any one with true experience hear.
I have considered CN_KEYDOWN, CN_KEYUP message but I do not know how to implement it correctly and I think I need a more encompassing message anyway.

```
procedure TBaseControl.KeyBourdProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  try
    with Message do
    begin
      case Msg of
        WM_KEYDOWN,
        WM_SYSKEYDOWN: if DoKeyDown(TWMKey(Message)) then Exit;
        WM_CHAR: if DoKeyPress(TWMKey(Message)) then Exit;
        WM_KEYUP,
        WM_SYSKEYUP: if DoKeyUp(TWMKey(Message)) then Exit;
        CN_KEYDOWN,
        CN_CHAR, CN_SYSKEYDOWN,
        CN_SYSCHAR:
        begin
          WndProc(Message);
          Exit;
        end;
      end;
      Result := CallWindowProc(FDefKBProc, FKBHandle, Msg, WParam, LParam);
    end;
  except
    Application.HandleException(Self);
  end;
end;
```

But this in my create is not correct

```
FDefKBProc := Pointer(GetWindowLong(FKBHandle, GWL_WNDPROC));
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. `TWinControl` already handles receiving keystrokes for you. If you want your control to respond to specific keystrokes while it has input focus, simply override the virtual `KeyDown()`, `KeyUp()`,  and `KeyPress()` methods.  If that does not address your issue, please edit your question to clarify the problem you are having.

Comment: This is the very thing I expect it to do but it does not at all. Delphi break points is clearly showing no thread is passing and code is not read. I have the basics like inherited...........; in place but nothing

Comment: I believe I'm in uncharted territory because all descendants of TCustomControl are Grids and no grid uses keyboard inputs. The edits added to TGrid do. So I'm also asking if TCustomControl is blocking keyboard data.

Comment: Not all descendents of `TCustomControl` are grids.  Is *your* custom control a grid?  It sounds like this question needs a lot more information...

Comment: Simply override the virtual methods that Remy mentions. Obviously if your form has KeyPreview set then your control isn't going to see the key events.

Comment: Correct me hear but I found GetParentForm(Self) in TGrid and its called to check focus is on self in function TCustomGrid.IsActiveControl: Boolean; And used for number of other event processes. But it does not set the objects parent. Why not???? I think this is my question I need to ask.

Comment: I found HandleAllocated in TGrid rather than using in my Create "parent TWinControl(AOwner);"  I have to ask the question way is the handle dropped so easily to call it so much.                                                           Correct me hear to but I found GetParentForm(Self) in TGrid and its called to check focus is on self in function TCustomGrid.IsActiveControl: Boolean; Both are used for number of other event processes. But it does not set the objects parent. Why not???? I think this is my question I need to ask.

Comment: David Heffernan: - I did not realise TForn.KeyPreview but its defaulted as false anyway.

Comment: The problem I have is an invalid handle and so the events did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all of the code in the question. Especially the part where you replace the window procedure. Instead simply override `KeyDown`, `KeyUp` or `KeyPress`, as appropriate, and add your handling there.